# SpatialPointDataFrame and queen contiguity neighbouring list

Tags: r

I wanted to do a queen contiguity neighboring list too, later on, check Moran's I. I know how to do it for a SpatialPolygonDataFrame `SPDF`:

```
Queen_Contiguity_Neighbour_List<-poly2nb(SPDF)
```

My problem is, however, that I have a SpatialPointDataFrame. For sure the usage of poly2nb does not work since this is done for polygons. My question is if there is a package/function who does such a neighbor list for a point data frame. If there is not such a thing, what can I use instead?

Comment: No reply means that this is not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of mathematics it should be clear, that making a queen contiguity matrix of a point dataset is not possible. Better is to use distance-based weighted matrixes. If you use these, the problem is solved.